# Data Recovery from old Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery

Hi to all Android Enthusiasts!

I have recently found one of my very first android phones, with many fond memories saved onto it.
Now I can not access the phones data any more since I entered my pattern wrong to many times back in the day.

Now even if I enter my current google credentials for the account I used during those times, the phone doesn't want to aknowledge that. I have double-checked several times it the password I entered was correct.

Since I don't seem to be able to access my phone via normal means, I was curious if there is a way to recover my data another way? I don't mind if the phone becomes unusable afterwards as well.
I have only very limited knowledge of android and all its abilities but I seem to remember reading about these older phones storage being easier to access than newer ones.

Is there anyone who could think of a way for me to recover my data?
Even if anyone has an idea why my phone asks me for my google login but doesn't accept it would be helpful.

I would really appreciate any help since those are a lot of memories that would be lost forever.

Comment: Your old phone should run Android 4 or 4.1 and as far as I know Google has stopped supporting those versions in Play Services (those old Android versions only support outdated and insecure TLS versions that can be one reason). This could be the reason the phone does not accept your credentials, it tries to check them online but the connection fails.